# Are there any drawbacks of the equivalent concept?

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox

I wanted to know because in certain reaction(disproportionation or Comproportionation) equivalent concept does not help much. In many question it is solved by balancing a reaction,but then what's the use of Equivalent method when we are just balancing it. 
  In short I want to know that in some case is it neccessary to balance the redox reaction ??

Please help by giving examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One drawback is that an "equivalent" may not be a well defined quantity.  Take phosphoric acid as an example.  The first deprotonation is fairly strong but the next two rapidly become weaker.  Therefore you need a rather strongly basic solution to get all three protons off; under more nearly neutral conditions you can remove only one or two protons.  So with respect to Bronsted-Lowry reactions does phosphoric acid have three equivalents per mole, or fewer?  You have to define the reaction conditions to pin it down.